# Raspberry Pi 3 - Serial comms in Python failing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, uart

After looking at MANY postings and tutorials regarding Serial communications on RPi3 (also tried aother Pi's, 2, 3 and 4) I am STILL NOT able to send/receive any serial comms to/from my Pi.

I want to send AT commands to a connected GSM module using Python, but it is like the serial is disabled.

I have tested the GSM module with an FTDI, and it works perfectly.

I have also made sure that the serial / UART is enabled on the Pi (using raspi-config) but I simply cannot get the AT commands to the GSM module.

Any thoughts/ideas welcome as I am completely stumped!

Below is a code snippet of a smiple "in/out" script provided by the GSM module manufacturer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",115200)
ser.flushInput()

command_input = ''
rec_buff = ''

try:
    while True:
        print("press Ctrl+C to exit")
        command_input = input('Please input the AT command:')
        ser.write((command_input + '\r\n').encode())
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if ser.inWaiting():
            time.sleep(0.01)
            rec_buff = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        if rec_buff != '':
            print("Output: ")
            print(rec_buff.decode())
            rec_buff = ''
except:
    if ser != None:
        ser.close()
```

Comment: have you confirmed that the device is showing up under /dev/ttyS0 and not a different port?

Comment: Yes, dmesg | grep tty shows what is expected.

I have made significant progress now - found 2 things that may have solved the comms isssue - but need to test to see which one (or if indeed both) did the trick.

1. Adding a ground wire between the module and the Pi
2. running: sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service

the 2nd action is the more likely candidate - even though I followed all the instructions on changing boot and cmdline configs...